# 'Prevented recursive attempt to activate part' when clicking on a marker

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef

I am creating my own GEF based graphical editor. It creates error markers when validation fails and the editor has a gotoMarker method to find and active the marker. This all works.

Only problem is that I get a RuntimeException when double clicking on the marker (when clicking 'GoTo' from the context menu there is no problem)
The message is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WARNING: Prevented recursive attempt to activate part org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView while still in the middle of activating part namespace.myEditorID`
```

Part of the corresponding stacktrace shows:

```
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3586)
...
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_enumerate_printers(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_enumerate_printers(OS.java:9296)
at org.eclipse.swt.printing.Printer.getPrinterList(Printer.java:98)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.actions.PrintAction.calculateEnabled(PrintAction.java:45)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.actions.WorkbenchPartAction.isEnabled(WorkbenchPartAction.java:123)
...
```

The complete stacktrace is a bit long, so it is available at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vGK1khan).

This gave me the idea to disable the printing action in [ActionBarContributor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/gef/ui/actions/ActionBarContributor.html).declareGlobalActionKeys by removing:

```
addGlobalActionKey(ActionFactory.PRINT.getId());
```

This solves the RuntimeException...?!

I do not see the relation between the Printing action and going to the corresponding object after clicking on a marker. Leaving the Printing action disabled, of course, is not a solution.

So what can I do to keep the Printing action available and prevent these RuntimeExceptions?

Comment: Do you have a fuller stack trace?  Where was your call to addGlobalAction key?

Comment: I cannot access the fuller stacktrace at the moment, I'll post it tomorrow. But basically it looks like (all) actions are being checked whether they need to be enabled or not. the `addGlobalActionKey` is/was called in `ActionBarContributor.declareGlobalActionKeys`

Comment: @katsharp I added a [link](http://pastebin.com/vGK1khan) the complete stacktrace

Comment: Hey, is it possible this is your problem? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355401

Comment: I have seen that bug report, it is stated fixed. But the fix itself is not really attached... Furthermore, bug report talks about being slow because the list of available is fetch over and over. Mine application is not slow, it generates exception because seems to be trying to activate the 'Problems view' and my editor (because it needs to go to the double clicked error). To me it seemed a different problem, even though the stack traces are very similar. But I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test ,I refer to the url:https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=154112
and I overrid my EditorPart's setFocus method like:

```
@Override
public void setFocus() {
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setFocus();
}
```

and then it works well.

Comment: Wow... Excellent!!! I had given up hope that my bug would get fixed... But you nailed it! Thanks a lot.